# Is it possible to inspect previous versions of versioned catalog layers?

Tags: here-olp

I'm looking at a catalog in the Data Portal:
https://platform.here.com/data

I can go to the "Inspect" tab to look at the tiles that are published for the current version. Is it possible to do so for previous versions of the layer?

Answer (score 1):

Check the top left corner of the "Inspect" window:

[image: top left corner]